# Why is my compiler trying to convert from signed long long to unsigned int

Tags: c++, type-conversion, physfs

The line

```
std::unique_ptr<PHYSFS_sint64> myBuf(new PHYSFS_sint64[PHYSFS_fileLength(myfile)]);
```

produces the warning

`warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'PHYSFS_sint64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data`

`PHYSFS_sint64` is a typedef for `singed long long`

`PHYSFS_fileLength` returns a `PHYSFS_sint64`.

So I don't understand why the compiler tries to convert from `signed long long` to `unsigned int` when I just try to assign a `signed long long` to a `signed long long`?

When I explicitly type `signed long long` instead of `PHYSFS_sint64` it still outputs the same warning

Am I being stupid right now? I don't get it

Comment: This unique pointer will call the wrong `delete` on destruction, which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB Could you elaborate please? I replaced the raw pointer that I was previously using with `unique_ptr` because I read it's safer. I thought I don't need to worry about deleting when using a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `std::vector`?

Comment: You are using `std::unique_ptr<T>` when you should be using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Comment: TartanLlama: Yep. It's because I don't know how to use it in this case :P JoachimPileborg: Thanks, got it!

Comment: Also, just to experiment and to help you understand *where* the problem actually is, can you try doing just e.g. `new PHYSFS_sint64[PHYSFS_fileLength(myfile)]`? Does that give you the same warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really given enough information, but the likely explanation is that  `size_t` (the type used to represent the range of array indexes and sizes supported by your implementation) is a 32-bit quantity.   Which means, to use a 64-bit integer (signed or not) as an array size, your compiler would convert it to 32-bit in some manner.

If this is correct, you will find that `size_t` and `unsigned int` with your compiler are the same (which the standard permits but does not require), and both are a 32-bit type (which, again, are permitted but not required).    Which probably all means you are using a 32-bit implementation.

An alternative - but highly unlikely - explanation is that you have a buggy compiler which does not handle the standard conversions between integral types of different sizes correctly in expressions.   I say unlikely, as a compiler with such bugginess is more likely to produce faulty executable code without a whimper, rather than giving warnings about it.

Comment: I'm not going to lose sleep over someone downvoting this, but an explanation of why might be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem `[PHYSFS_fileLength(myfile)]`...

You are using it as an index (or size of array). Indices,sizes are unsigned. Usually (I said usually because I am not sure about all cases), indices are `size_t` which is platform dependable but it is always `unsigned`

Comment: Welcome, for sizes and indices you may use size_t always which will reduce much overhead....

Comment: Except for the fact that iterator arithmetic is defined on `ptrdiff_t`, so while you can write `v[uns]`, you can't write `*(v.begin() + uns)` without getting a "converting from unsigned to signed" warning.